# How to read from DataStore Preferences to string?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-datastore

Im trying to use datastore inside Composable to read user data but cant read the value as string to put inside Text.
That's the datastore

```
private val Context.userPreferencesDataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
  name = "user"
)
private val USER_FIRST_NAME = stringPreferencesKey("user_first_name")
suspend fun saveUserToPreferencesStore(context: Context) {
  context.userPreferencesDataStore.edit { preferences ->
    preferences[USER_FIRST_NAME] = "user1"
  }
}
fun getUserFromPreferencesStore(context: Context): Flow<String> = context.userPreferencesDataStore.data
  .map { preferences ->
    preferences[USER_FIRST_NAME] ?: ""
  }
```

and inside Composable:

```
@Composable
fun myComposable() {
  var context = LocalContext.current
  LaunchedEffect( true){
    saveUserToPreferencesStore(context )
  
  }
  Text(getUserFromPreferencesStore(context ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so in your code, `getUserFromPreferencesStore()` is returning a Flow. so you should collect that as flow, and then compose will auto update once the data is being changed. For example (something similar to this):

```
val user by getUserFromPreferencesStore(context).collectAsStateWithLifecycleAware(initValue)
```